# Is there a way to get the latest value of element in GTM

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

I have this line from google tag manager,

```
function(){
 try{
   return document.getElementById('prodid').value;
 }catch(e){
    return 0;
 }
}
```

The question is, is there a way to get the latest value of the prodId onClick? There are variance of products in one product page. So i need to get the last prodId of the last clicked variance/product. Currently, upon checking the id being fetched from google tag manager is not updating. Im using the chrome extension in checking

[image]

[image]

```
function(){
   var ce = {{Click Element}};
   // Now you can use ce and scrape for information on the page related to the element that was last clicked. If jQuery is loaded then it may be easier to get what you need.

   // Totally fake example
   var prodId = $('ce').closest('#prodid').text();
   return prodId;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The built-in `Click Element` variable always refers to the last element that was clicked and detected by the click listeners. You can always write up a custom JavaScript variable that uses that `Click Element` and even manipulate it if you need to DOM scrape for information.

```
function(){
   var ce = {{Click Element}};
   // Now you can use ce and scrape for information on the page related to the element that was last clicked. If jQuery is loaded then it may be easier to get what you need.

   // Totally fake example
   var prodId = $('ce').closest('#prodid').text();
   return prodId;
}
```

Comment: how to declare {{Click Element}}? I just tried copy-paste. i threw me this error: Unknown variable 'Click Element' found in another variable. Edit the variable and remove the reference to the unknown variable.

Comment: `{{Click Element}}` is a built-in GTM variable that you may need to enable. Go to Variables, and click the red Configure button, and then check "Click Element".

Comment: thanks. But the value shown by the tag assistant isn't changing still.

Comment: Oh, I didn't mean for you to copy my code exactly. It was meant to serve as a model, but you'll need to do the scraping properly, which depends greatly on your HTML structure. You'll have to traverse your DOM until you find the `#prodId` ID.

Comment: For those returning here, because they get this error. 

This means the Built-in variable, has not been added to the workspace.

To do so, do the following:

Go to Variables > Built-In Variables > Click in Configure

Under Clicks, check the "Click Element" variable, and hit save.

Then try to publish your changes again, you will see the error will disappear